# How to set dynamic height of parent(relative) based on height of responsive images in absolute container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a relative parent element that has multiple absolute child elements which wraps and adds rows of the images inside at bottom when the screen gets smaller. I wanted to achieve a height that resizes according to the height of its child element. However, my jquery code keeps adding the value on top of each other when resizing resulting in a large number. How can I achieve a height that changes when the window resizes and just get the last value.

Tried logging it on the console. Seems to work fine. However, what I wanted is just to get the last value and assign it as height when the window resizes.

http://evertaste-lislam.ga/ <--- This is the website im working with. Its the image gallery in the homepage.

```js
$(window).resize(function () {
  var pgContHeight = $('.pg-container').height();
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth >= 992) {
    pgContHeight *= 2; //<--Number of rows multiplied by height of image//
  } else if (windowWidth <= 991 && windowWidth >= 768) {
    pgContHeight *= 3;
  } else if (windowWidth <= 767 && windowWidth >= 601) {
    pgContHeight *= 4;
  } else if (windowWidth <= 600) {
    pgContHeight *= 8;
  }
  $('.photo-gallery-container').css('height', +pgContHeight + 'px');
})
$(window).trigger('resize');
})
```

```css
.photo-gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.photo-gallery-row-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.pg-container {
  width: 25%; //**Width changes via media queries**//
  position: relative;
}

.pg-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo-gallery-container">
  <div class="photo-gallery-row-1">  <!-- I have 3 of these positioned absolute -->
    <div class="pg-container">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src='//via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src='//via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src='//via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src=//via.placeholder.com/350x150>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img src='//via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to accomplish. Is that a responsive images' gallery? If so, you don't necessarily have to use javascript to reach your goal. Do you know the padding bottom tricks? It allows you to define a width and then a height (via the padding bottom) with a ratio to that width (for exemple, you want square images, you need a 1/1 ratio like if your width is 25%, then your padding bottom will be 25%) etc...
I don't necesseraly find the usefullness of javascript here but maybe your absolute positionning is important so I'll wait for some clarification from you. Hope I helped!

```css
.photo-gallery-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:100px;
 }

.photo-gallery-row-1{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:wrap;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: -1%;
 }

.pg-container { 
    margin: 1%;
    width: 23%;      
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    position: relative;
    
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('//via.placeholder.com/350x150');
 }
 
 @media screen and (max-width:40rem) {
  .pg-container {
    width: 31%;
    padding-bottom: 31%;
  }
 }
 
 /*Etc....*/
```

```html
<div class="photo-gallery-container">
  <div class="photo-gallery-row-1">
    <div class="pg-container">
       <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
       <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
       <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
       <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-container">
       <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is an image gallery where there are buttons a user can click to make the absolute container appear one at a time. However i have multiple containers(absolute) positioned on top of each other inside the relative parent and i want it have a have a dynamic height so that it would still occupy a space in the document flow.

Comment: http://evertaste-lislam.ga/.. this is the website im working with. the image gallery is in the homepage. i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This question got complicated because of the idea behind how the approach was and how it should work in JS. I found out that i can simply use `data-filter` and just eliminate the idea of using absolute positioning when creating image galleries or portfolio galleries like this.